# Passing a textfield value from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My question may sound naive, but really struggling to do a very simple thing. Suppose I have to html page - `send.html` and `receive.html`.

In `send.html` page -

I have text field and a button in like following -

`<body>
    <form onsubmit="recieve.html">
        <input type="text" id="mytextfield">
        <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Go">
    </form>
</body>`

Here I want to put something on the textfield and I want to see that value in the receive page some thing like - Hello 'value of textfield'. That's it.

Do I need to use JS cookie for that? If not, how can I do it in the most simple way?

Need help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript you can write a function to store the value in a cookie and read it on the next page.  By the way, your page goes in the `action` attribute.  `onsubmit` expects a javascript function, not a page.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is [PHP](http://php.net). Bottom line is you need something handling the data on the server side.

Comment: Well, my client side code is written in JS ... That's why I was wondering how to do it in a simple way.

Comment: @Pow when it gets posted, it's sent to the server to then be served back to the client. So you **really** need something server-side.

Comment: I'm handling some server side php files as well with simple GET. Do you think that might help?

Comment: I don't think using method get is any good except for some very specific situations - which I don't think to be the case here. You'd need to set the method of the form to post (then get rid of that onsubmit unless you want to do something before it hits the server on the client-side). On the PHP page/script, handle the data through the $_POST array.